# Installing Tcl and Tix in OSX

Tags: macos, python

I'm having trouble installing Tix on OSX the version of Tix I am using is 8.4.3. I try to install it by following the instructions in the README

```
% ./configure
% make
% make install
```

And iat the very start of make it gives me:

```
xXpm.o tixUnixWm.o  -L/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework -ltclstub8.5 -L/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework -ltkstub8.5 
ld: warning: in /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/libtclstub8.5.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: in /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/libtkstub8.5.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols:

(A whole long list of things)


at the very end
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libTix8.4.3.dylib] Error 1
```

Edit: Here's all the errors in the middle..

```
ld: warning: in /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/libtclstub8.5.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: in /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/libtkstub8.5.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols:
  "_Tk_InitStubs", referenced from:
      _Tix_Init in tixInit.o
  "_Tcl_InitStubs", referenced from:
      _Tix_Init in tixInit.o
  "_tclStubsPtr", referenced from:
      _FreeParseOptions in tixClass.o
      _FreeParseOptions in tixClass.o
      _Tix_UninitializedClassCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_UninitializedClassCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_InstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _Tix_CreateInstanceCmd in tixClass.o
      _SetupAttribute in tixClass.o
      _SetupAttribute in tixClass.o
      _SetupAttribute in tixClass.o
      _ClassTableDeleteProc in tixClass.o
      _CreateClassRecord in tixClass.o
      _InitClass in tixClass.o
      _InitClass in tixClass.o
      _InitClass in tixClass.o
      _InitClass in tixClass.o
      _InitClass in tixClass.o
      _InitClass in tixClass.o
      _InitClass in tixClass.o
      _InitClass in tixClass.o

      _Tix_ClassCmd in tixClass.o
      _EventProc in tixCmds.o
      _IdleHandler in tixCmds.o
      _MapEventProc in tixCmds.o
      _MapEventProc in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_GetDefaultCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_GetDefaultCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_TmpLineCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_ParentWindow in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_ParentWindow in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_DoWhenMappedCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_DoWhenMappedCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_DoWhenMappedCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_DoWhenIdleCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_DoWhenIdleCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_DoWhenIdleCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_DoWhenIdleCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_DoWhenIdleCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_HandleOptionsCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_HandleOptionsCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_HandleOptionsCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_HandleOptionsCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_HandleOptionsCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_HandleOptionsCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_HandleOptionsCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_HandleOptionsCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_Get3DBorderCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_Get3DBorderCmd in tixCmds.o
      _Tix_Get3DBorderCmd in tixCmds.o
      _tixStrDup in tixCompat.o
      _Tix_ArgcError in tixError.o
      _Tix_ValueMissingError in tixError.o
      _Tix_UnknownPublicMethodError in tixError.o
      _FreeClientStruct in tixGe
```

Comment: The `(A whole long list of things)` is the important part, without which nobody can help you except by wild guessing.

Comment: Oh yes you are probably right. :) Edited

Comment: Ok, the first two lines of that tell you the real problem: you're linking a 64-bit version of tix against a 32-bit Tcl framework. You could try using `arch i386 make`, but I'd want to find out why it's defaulting to 64-bit building if the system is 32-bit.

Comment: I see. That is pretty odd. In the ./configure it says the default is 32 bit and you have to specify --enable-64bit to use 64 bit.

Comment: Have the same issue, tried ./configure --disable-64bit with no result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Doing configure with different arguments in a previously used working directory doesn't always have the expected results in my experience. Did you try a fully cleaned working directory?